# How to convert coordinates on Bitmap to real coordiates on Image View displayed on screen

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, bitmap, imageview

I have an Image View which displays an image (e.g 2000x1000 pixels) and I have a coordinate (X,Y) on that image (not the image view). The canvas of my Image View is 600x800 for example. How can I convert the point (X,Y) to screen coordinate so that I can draw a path with them on the OnDraw(...) method of Image View. Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Update: If I use matrix to draw the path between coordinates, it works but the path and objects i draw become really small. Here is the code i used.

```
final Matrix matrix = canvas.getMatrix();
matrix.preConcat( _view.getImageMatrix() );
matrix.preScale( 1.0f /_inSampleSize, 1.0f / _inSampleSize);
canvas.setMatrix( matrix );
//I draw the path here
```

Update: I add a picture to show the effect when using matrix to draw the path. I would like to have the 4 line and the 4 corner balls to be in normal size. The red color is the boundary of the Image View which holds the picture.
[image]

Comment: "become really small" Can you post any screenshots? Like, is the scale factor just wrong?

Comment: @Jenny I just posted the screenshot for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "normal" size, but assume you expect to have the lines and circles be larger. That's not in my area of expertise. Might want to open a new question for that one.  Possibly they are "normal" sized for the huge bitmap, and then shrunk down (like everything else) to fit in the view?

Answer (score 0):

I think that might depend on how exactly you are displaying your image.  Your ImageView (600x800) is not the same aspect ratio as your bitmap (2000x1000).

You are keeping the bitmap's aspect ratio stable as you scale it down? If so, which part (height or width) takes up the full screen and which has black (or whatever else) as padding?  This will help you determine your scale factor.

```
scale_factor = goal_height/height1;  //if height is what you are scaling by
scale_factor = goal_width/width1;  //if width is what you are scaling by.
```

I would try:

```
x_goal = x1 * scale_factor;
y_goal = y1 * scale_factor;
```

That is, if you have a point (1333, 900) in your image, and your image takes up the full width, you would multiply both x and y by 600/2000 to get (399.9, 270).  (you might want to round that decimal).

If you are NOT keeping the bitmaps aspect ratio stable (that is, you're squeezing it to fit), then you'd have a height_scale_factor and a width_scale factor.  So you'd take (1333,900) and multiply x by 600/2000 and y by 800/1000 to get (399.9,720).

Comment: Hi @Jenny I actually tried the scale factor as you mentioned, but it does not work for me. I want the coordinates to be exactly on screen since I am doing document edge detection on the image.

Comment: If you can't handle rounding errors, then you might not have a choice other than making the Image you're rendering the same size as the ImageView. If the rounding errors are not the issue, then I'm confused as to how standard scaling is rendering your image fine, but not your drawings.