# How to convert opencv Mat coordinates to Layout coordinates in android?

Tags: java, opencv, kotlin, android

I'm building an image cropper in android with the help of opencv. The application captures an image from the camera intent and is taken to crop activity with predetermined boundaries which are based on the logos in the image. The issue is that I'm not able to display the predetermined boundaries accurate to the image.

There is a need for scaling factor which will be used to convert the opencv's mat coordinates to layout coordinates to display the boundaries accurately.

Actual Results ->  https://ibb.co/5WDxCqR

Expected Results

The green boundary rectangle must appear on the "Energy" logo

Similar question found at opencv but no solution is provided (https://answers.opencv.org/question/186911/how-to-convert-mat-coordinates-to-layout-coordinates-in-android/)

```
package com.example.ccsim.view

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import com.example.ccsim.processor.Corners
import com.example.ccsim.processor.SourceManager
import org.opencv.core.Point
import org.opencv.core.Size

class PaperRectangle : FrameLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributes)
    constructor(context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet, defTheme: Int) : super(context, attributes, defTheme)

    private val rectPaint = Paint()
    private val circlePaint = Paint()
    private var ratioX: Double = 1.0
    private var ratioY: Double = 1.0
    private var xOffset: Double = 1.0
    private var yOffset: Double = 1.0
    private var ratio: Double = 1.0
    private var tl: Point = Point()
    private var tr: Point = Point()
    private var br: Point = Point()
    private var bl: Point = Point()
    private val path: Path = Path()
    private var point2Move = Point()
    private var cropMode = false
    private var latestDownX = 0.0F
    private var latestDownY = 0.0F

    init {
        rectPaint.color = Color.GREEN
        rectPaint.isAntiAlias = true
        rectPaint.isDither = true
        rectPaint.strokeWidth = 6F
        rectPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        rectPaint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND    // set the join to round you want
        rectPaint.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND      // set the paint cap to round too
        rectPaint.pathEffect = CornerPathEffect(10f)

        circlePaint.color = Color.RED
        circlePaint.isDither = true
        circlePaint.isAntiAlias = true
        circlePaint.strokeWidth = 4F
        circlePaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    }

    fun onCorners2Crop(
        corners: Corners?,
        size: Size?
    ) {

        cropMode = true
        tl = corners?.corners?.get(0) ?: SourceManager.defaultTl
        tr = corners?.corners?.get(1) ?: SourceManager.defaultTr
        br = corners?.corners?.get(2) ?: SourceManager.defaultBr
        bl = corners?.corners?.get(3) ?: SourceManager.defaultBl
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        (context as Activity).windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        //exclude status bar height
        val statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight(context)
        val navigationBarHeight = getNavigationBarHeight(context)
        val width1 = size?.width ?: 1.0
        val height1 = size?.height ?: 1.0
        val width2 = (displayMetrics.widthPixels).toDouble()
        val height2 = (displayMetrics.heightPixels - navigationBarHeight).toDouble()
        ratioX = width2.div(width1)
        ratioY = height2.div(height1)
        Log.i("*****Ratio X",ratioX.toString())
        Log.i("*****Ratio Y",ratioY.toString())
        Log.i("*****width 1",width1.toString())
        Log.i("*****height 1",height1.toString())
        Log.i("*****width 2",width2.toString())
        Log.i("*****height 2",height2.toString())
        Log.i("******BEFORE RESIZE","*******")
        Log.i("******tl",tl.toString())
        Log.i("******tr",tr.toString())
        Log.i("******br",br.toString())
        Log.i("******bl",bl.toString())
        reverseSize()
        Log.i("******After RESIZE","*******")
        Log.i("******tl",tl.toString())
        Log.i("******tr",tr.toString())
        Log.i("******br",br.toString())
        Log.i("******bl",bl.toString())
        movePoints()
    }

    fun getCorners2Crop(): List<Point> {
        resize()
        return listOf(tl, tr, br, bl)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas?.drawPath(path, rectPaint)
        if (cropMode) {
            canvas?.drawCircle(tl.x.toFloat(), tl.y.toFloat(), 20F, circlePaint)
            canvas?.drawCircle(tr.x.toFloat(), tr.y.toFloat(), 20F, circlePaint)
            canvas?.drawCircle(bl.x.toFloat(), bl.y.toFloat(), 20F, circlePaint)
            canvas?.drawCircle(br.x.toFloat(), br.y.toFloat(), 20F, circlePaint)
        }
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

        if (!cropMode) {
            return false
        }
        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                latestDownX = event.x
                latestDownY = event.y
                calculatePoint2Move(event.x, event.y)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                point2Move.x = (event.x - latestDownX) + point2Move.x
                point2Move.y = (event.y - latestDownY) + point2Move.y
                movePoints()
                latestDownY = event.y
                latestDownX = event.x
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun calculatePoint2Move(downX: Float, downY: Float) {
        val points = listOf(tl, tr, br, bl)
        point2Move = points.minBy { Math.abs((it.x - downX).times(it.y - downY)) } ?: tl
    }

    private fun movePoints() {
        path.reset()
        path.moveTo(tl.x.toFloat(), tl.y.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(tr.x.toFloat(), tr.y.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(br.x.toFloat(), br.y.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(bl.x.toFloat(), bl.y.toFloat())
        path.close()
        invalidate()
    }


    private fun resize() {
        tl.x = tl.x.div(ratioX)
        tl.y = tl.y.div(ratioY)
        tr.x = tr.x.div(ratioX)
        tr.y = tr.y.div(ratioY)
        br.x = br.x.div(ratioX)
        br.y = br.y.div(ratioY)
        bl.x = bl.x.div(ratioX)
        bl.y = bl.y.div(ratioY)
    }

    private fun reverseSize() {
        tl.x = tl.x.times(ratioX)
        tl.y = tl.y.times(ratioY)
        tr.x = tr.x.times(ratioX)
        tr.y = tr.y.times(ratioY)
        br.x = br.x.times(ratioX)
        br.y = br.y.times(ratioY)
        bl.x = bl.x.times(ratioX)
        bl.y = bl.y.times(ratioY)
    }

    private fun getNavigationBarHeight(pContext: Context): Int {
        val resources = pContext.resources
        val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
        return if (resourceId > 0) {
            resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
        } else 0
    }

    private fun getStatusBarHeight(pContext: Context): Int {
        val resources = pContext.resources
        val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
        return if (resourceId > 0) {
            resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
        } else 0
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341385/how-to-convert-coordinates-on-bitmap-to-real-coordiates-on-image-view-displayed maybe this??

Comment: Can you post your code to see what you did wrong?

Comment: @RedaHammoud please find the source code.

Answer (score 0):

So, you may use OpenCV C++ binding through Android JNI. In that way there are no such problem, cause Android camera and OpenCV code computing the same image buffer. For example read [this](https://medium.com/@betakuang/using-native-opencv-code-in-android-projects-3aa311cddb28) article.